# How to pre-populate drop down list when form submitted on same page?

Tags: php, html, forms, session

I have made a filter using a form with drop down lists. The filter is used to filter results from a mySQL database. The form is processed on the same page as the results. I want to make it so that the filter drop down lists retain the filter parameters once the results have been filtered.

I have done this in the past by using a session, however that was when I used another page to process the query. I have tried to apply this same theory but it isn't working. I have searched this site as well as Google and I have only found answers related to a separate page for processing.

Currently the code that I have will only pre-populate the form after it has been submitted twice. The first time it is submitted it shows the default setting of "Select..."

Here are the relevant sections of my code:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['submitted_filter_values']))
{
extract($_SESSION['submitted_filter_values']);
}

<form action="#filter" method="post" name="filter">
<table>

<tr>
<td>
<select name="prefix">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option <?php if(isset($prefix) && $prefix == "PDM"){echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?> value="PDM">PDM</option>
<option <?php if(isset($prefix) && $prefix == "TB"){echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?> value="TB">TB</option>
<option <?php if(isset($prefix) && $prefix == "JNL"){echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?> value="JNL">JNL</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr align="center">
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="btn_150x30" name="submit" value="Filter Results"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>

$_SESSION['submitted_filter_values'] = $_REQUEST;
```

I have tried placing the session variable in different locations but that didn't work. I thought maybe refreshing the page would work but then I figured it would effectively remove the filter like it does when I submit the form twice. Interesting point to note is that is it very consistent in that it works literally every second time I submit it, so every odd submit it does not populate and every even submit it populates.

Comment: You say you want to keep the `select` element `value` field across `POST`s, but do you also really want to keep that setting session wide?

Comment: where are you declaring the $prefix variable?

Comment: @didierc you raise a fantastic point. I don't necessarily need it to be session wide, I've obviously just learned a lesson as to why I don't try to make something work on a different application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing that the session wasn't a good idea for my application, because it is only being used on one page and not throughout the site, I have taken a fresh approach to the problem.

At the top of my filter I have this for each option:

```
if(isset($_POST['prefix']))
    {
    $prefix = $_POST['prefix'];
    }
```

Then in my drop down list, I have this for each option:

```
<option <?php if(isset($prefix) && $prefix == "PDM"){echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?> value="PDM">PDM</option>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['prefix'])){
        // if the form has been posted use it
        $prefix = $_POST['prefix']; // <------ RUN SOME VALIDATION HERE!!!!!!!
        $_SESSION['submitted_filter_values'] = $prefix; // update the session var

    }elseif(isset($_SESSION['submitted_filter_values'])){
        // if the form hasn't been posted then look in the $_SESSION
        $prefix = $_SESSION['submitted_filter_values']; // <------ RUN SOME VALIDATION HERE (trust no one!)!!!!!!!
    }



?>
    <form action="#filter" method="post" name="filter">
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="prefix">
                        <option value="">Select...</option>
                        <option<?php if($prefix == "PDM"){echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?> value="PDM">PDM</option>
                        <option<?php if($prefix == "TB"){echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?> value="TB">TB</option>
                        <option<?php if($prefix == "JNL"){echo " selected=\"selected\"";} ?> value="JNL">JNL</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn_150x30" name="submit" value="Filter Results" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: I have several fields acting as a filter, I didn't post them all as I didn't expect the answer to go in this direction. Also, I usually post too much code and it gets edited out by someone, so I was trying to avoid that. Now I'm convinced that I should start from scratch and not use a session at all, like I said in the comments above, I don't think I should have tried to apply this code to this application. For this application the posted information does not go beyond this one page, so now a session seems...well...stupid. Regardless, thank you very much for your informative reply. +1 :)

Comment: Ah ok - I went for simplicity :) It will pay to add some sort of validation to the inputs if other people use it to protect your application

Answer (score 2):

It's a request and session issue you have. If I follow the processing of your script right, you have the following situation:

On first submit, the session `submitted_filter_values` is not set. You will see the default entry, `$prefix` remains unset.

On second submit you then set the session `submitted_filter_values` *after* you have output the select tag. You will still see default entry then because of that order.

On the third submit you will see the filter of the second submit.

On the fourth submit you will see the filter of the third submit. And so on and so forth.

If you don't submit but just request via GET, you that value remains however you also set the session `submitted_filter_values` back to default because `$_REQUEST` does not contain `prefix` any longer.

Seeing this order also helps to change the script. One rule of thumb is to handle the input variables - set or not - on top of the script. While writing @Chris already provided code for this - I would have done that a little different, but his example shows how it can work.

I would first of all define the filter(s) on top, process them one after the other both with the request and session logic, then output the form. This has the benefit that you change the data-logic on top and the output logic in the output.

```
<?php
session_start();

/**
 * define your filter(s)
 */
$filters = array(
    'prefix' => array(
        'value' => null,
        'list' => array('PDM', 'TB', 'JNL')
    )
);

$filtersSessionName = 'submitted_filter_values';

/**
 * process the state of your filter(s) with request input and
 * session state
 */
foreach($filters as $name => $filter) {

    // does request has filter value set?
    if (isset($_REQUEST[$name])) {
        $requestValue = $_REQUEST[$name];
        // does it validate?
        if (in_array($requestValue, $filter['list'])) {
            $filter['value'] = $requestValue;
            $_SESSION[$filtersSessionName][$name] = $requestValue;
            continue;
        }
    }

    // does the session has filter value set?
    if (isset($_SESSION[$filtersSessionName][$name])) {
        $sessionValue = $_SESSION[$filtersSessionName][$name];
        // does it validate?
        if (in_array($sessionValue, $filter[$list])) {
            $filter['value'] = $sessionValue;
            continue;
        }
    }
}


/**
 * output the filter(s) in the form
 */
?>

<form action="#filter" method="post" name="filter">
    <table>
        <?php foreach($filters as $name => $filter) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                        <option value="">Select ...</option>
                        <?php foreach($filter['values'] as $label) {
                            $selected = $filter['value'] === $label;
                        ?>
                            <option <?php if ($selected) { echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="<?php echo $label ?>">
                                <?php echo $label ?>
                            </option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } # foreach filters ?>
        <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="btn_150x30" name="submit" value="Filter Results"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

This can be further improved by using key/value pairs for the filter lists, so that the label of a filter can differ from the value that is being submitted. Also the `$_REQUEST` variables could be prefixed as well so that the name of the filter would be namespaced with the request variables like it is already done in the session.

Comment: Honestly, your post just made me realize how much I don't know about this language. I would be embarrassed to show you how I made my filter! Yes, it works, but I'm now positive it's very inefficient. I have quite a few more filter options involved, and I'm now convinced that I need to look at this from a different (read: easier) perspective. +1 for some excellent information, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the way you process your `$REQUEST` result.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($REQUEST))  // do we have a submitted request?
{         // yes -> save it in session

    $_SESSION['submitted_filter_values']['prefix'] = $REQUEST['prefix'];
    $prefix = $REQUEST['prefix'];

} else {  // no -> try to retrieve it from the session

   if(isset($_SESSION['submitted_filter_values']))
   {
      $prefix = extract($_SESSION['submitted_filter_values']['prefix']);
   }

}
?>

<form action="#filter" method="post" name="filter">
<table>

<tr>
<td>
<select name="prefix">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option <?php if(isset($prefix) && $prefix == "PDM"){echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?> value="PDM">PDM</option>
<option <?php if(isset($prefix) && $prefix == "TB"){echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?> value="TB">TB</option>
<option <?php if(isset($prefix) && $prefix == "JNL"){echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?> value="JNL">JNL</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr align="center">
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="btn_150x30" name="submit" value="Filter Results"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Regarding `extract`, it's very bad practice to use it with untrusted input like the $REQUEST array, which may contain unwanted values. Imagine someone forging an URL targeting that page with some parameters overriding certain values in your script, since you use $REQUEST, you would extract these values and potentially overwrite your variables with dangerous values.
That's why I am only copying the `prefix` value from the $REQUEST array.

Comment: Thank you for the info regarding the use of `extract` and `$REQUEST` together. This project is running only on a company server for internal use, however I don't ever want to purposely code something just because it will never be vulnerable. +1 for your information.

Comment: Even if in a trusted environment, you never know what clients might come up with when trying to solve a problem they have before getting back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, As per your current snippet code, you need to set sequence of your code as below

```
if(isset($_REQUEST))
{
   $_SESSION['submitted_filter_values'] = $_REQUEST;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['submitted_filter_values']))
{
   extract($_SESSION['submitted_filter_values']);
   unset($_SESSION['submitted_filter_values']);
}
```